# Am I a UX designer?

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer

Hey guys how are you doing?
I have a question.

I work in a small web design agency doing UI design, they work at a very fast pace, and sometimes some aspects aren't taken into consideration when designing a page, like UX.

Because we can't afford group tests or gathering real UX research information, I always try to apply UX practices to the project, like interpreting the briefing, doing some research on other websites to understand how they act and communicate with their customers.

With this in mind, I try to have a kind of a benchmark, applying some human decision bias in the process and some iteration. Basically trying to place myself in the user's shoes.

Is this considerate UX, and can I call myself UX designer doing this alternative way of research?

I would appreciate your most honest feedback.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this is more of a discussion topic than a UX problem in need of a solution, and so isn't suited to this Q&A site.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to avoid getting hung up on job titles, they are usually very generic and do not contain enough information as to what the role may or may not involve.

> Am I a UX designer?

This is the wrong question. What you should be asking is: *"Do I have experience with UX design?"*

For example, if you go for a new job advertising for a UX Designer, they will not ask you "what was your last job title?"... they will ask: "what experience do you have with UX design".

Now to answer the question, I cannot say for sure how much experience you have - ultimately that is for you to sell as and when the need to do so arises. However, I can say that you certainly have an awareness of UX design. You at least have a basic understanding of what it involves and likely some understanding of why it is important.

As a comment of your current situation, you seem to being doing the best you can with what you are given. Having a dedicated UX (or even UI) person is not always common in software development companies, especially the smaller ones. The fact you know there is more out there to learn, and actively try to learn and apply it, stands well for you on a personal level too. UX knowledge is always going to be a useful attribute, even if you stay on the UI path.